# Why does normalization change undefined characters to 'a'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode-normalization

I am attempting to write a script that will Normalize artist names stored in my MP3 files.  The issue I am running into is that the unicodedata.normalize function referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string) translates most accented characters to 'a'.  Here is the code and output

```
def remove_accents(data):
return ''.join(x for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', data) if x in string.ascii_letters).lower()

string2 = "Mötley Crüe"

string3 = makeEnglish3.convertChars(string2)
print(string3)
```

Output

```
matleycrae
```

I would expect motleycrue, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming `makeEnglish3.convertChars(string2)` is supposed to say `remove_accents(string2)` (and that your indentation error isn't in your actual code), this works fine for me, and returns `motleycrue`.

Comment: What’s the output of `print(repr(string2))`? Your original string probably isn’t what you expect it to be; ö is `c3 b6` in UTF-8, and U+00C3 is “À”.

Comment: Ugh, figured out the issue.  Had this at the top of my file.

# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

Comment: You could post that as an answer. Other people might also run into this issue

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what happens when this latin1 string is printed.

```
# -- coding: latin-1 --
string2 = "Mötley Crüe"
print(string2)
```

It prints `MÃ¶tley CrÃ¼e`. Notice that the characters after `Ã` are **not** alphabetical. In the following snippet, which is essentially your `remove_accents()` function, it's going to strip the non-alphabetical characters out:

```
import unicodedata
for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', string2):
    if x in string.ascii_letters:
       print(x, end='')
```

outputs `MAtleyCrAe`. Even using a string with different combining characters like `shåpÈ` still prints as `shÃ¥pÃ`, because *the byte sequences in your python file are being interpreted as latin1*, even though your file is saved in the filesystem as UTF-8.

#### Why are characters are being read as 'Ã'?

Lets check the byte composition of these characters:

```
>>> bytes('ö', 'utf-8')
b'\xc3\xb6'
>>> bytes('ü', 'utf-8')
b'\xc3\xbc'
>>> bytes('ö', 'utf-8').decode('latin1')
'Ã¶'
>>> bytes('ü', 'utf-8').decode('latin1')
'Ã¼'
```

You can see that these accented characters are represented as `\xc3` followed by some other hex number. In latin1, `\xc3` is Ã. Since the other character could possibly translate into a letter too, you might see Ã followed by a random letter too. This is what's making 'a' in your output (after you remove the accent and turn it to lowercase).